# A question about axis in tensorflow.stack (tensorflow= 1.14)

Tags: tensorflow

Using `tensorflow.stack` what does it mean to have `axis=-1` ?

I'm using `tensorflow==1.14`

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `axis=-1` simply means to stack the tensors along the *last* axis (as per the python list indexing syntax).

Let's take a look at how this looks like using these tensors of shape `(2, 2)`:

```py
>>> x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = tf.constant([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> z = tf.constant([[9, 10], [11, 12]])
```

---

The default behavior for `tf.stack` as described in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) is to stack the tensors along the first axis (index `0`) resulting in a tensor of shape `(3, 2, 2)`

```py
>>> tf.stack([x, y, z], axis=0) 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]], dtype=int32)>
```

---

Using `axis=-1`, the three tensors are stacked along the last axis instead, resulting in a tensor of shape `(2, 2, 3)`

```py
>>> tf.stack([x, y, z], axis=-1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 2,  6, 10]],

       [[ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 4,  8, 12]]], dtype=int32)>
```